# How to get row number for each null value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, row-number

I need to get row number for each record of null by sequence. Restart number when get a value in the row.

I have tried so far

```
select *
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) rn
from @tbl 

select *
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by value order by id) rn
from @tbl
```

```
declare @tbl table(id int, value int)
insert into @tbl values 
(1, null), (2, null), (3, null), (4, 1),(5, null), (6, null), (7, 1), (8, null), (9, null), (10, null)

select *
     , ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by value order by id) rn
from @tbl
```

I'm getting this:

```
id, value,  rn
1   NULL    1
2   NULL    2
3   NULL    3
4   1       4
5   NULL    5
6   NULL    6
7   1       7
8   NULL    8
9   NULL    9
10  NULL    10
```

I want a result like this

```
id, value,  rn
1   NULL    1
2   NULL    2
3   NULL    3
4   1       1
5   NULL    1
6   NULL    2
7   1       1
8   NULL    1
9   NULL    2
10  NULL    3
```

How can I get desired result with sql query?

Comment: What happens if `value` is some other non `NULL` value, other than 1?

Comment: only need to get the row number for null value records (other values doesn't matter)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach uses `COUNT` as an analytic function over the `value` column to generate "groups" for each block of `NULL` values.  To see how this works, just run `SELECT * FROM cte` using the code below.  Then, using this computed group, we use `ROW_NUMBER` to generate the sequences for the `NULL` values.  We order ascending by the value, which would mean that each `NULL` row number sequence would always begin with 1, which is the behavior we want.  For records with a non `NULL` value, we just pull that value across into the `rn` column.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, COUNT(value) OVER (ORDER BY id) vals
    FROM @tbl
)

SELECT id, value,
    CASE WHEN value IS NULL
         THEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY vals ORDER BY value)
         ELSE value END AS rn
FROM cte
ORDER BY id;
```

[image]

### Demo